# Accessing the Primary EMail ID in Android mobile using Firemonkey/Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8, delphi-10-seattle

I'm using Delphi 10 Seattle for developing mobile application. In android mobile, how can I able to get the primary E-Mail address using Delphi 10 Seattle or Delphi XE8. I have found [accessing the Primary e-mail using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address) and please provide some example for accessing the primary E-Mail using Delphi.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the same typical problem all us D10 Android developers face: we have java code examples of what we want to do and now we have to translate (wrap) that in Delphi API code. It's do-able but not easy. See my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262554) where I ran into a similar problem. Compare my Delphi api code to the Android doc's for the ActivityManager class and, if you are _good_, you'll see the pattern.

Comment: See the detailed answer to a similar SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39581114/2817399