# Delphi XE10 Seattle Android Get Notification From Service

Tags: android, delphi, android-service, delphi-10-seattle

I'm trying to make an application with local service, with an example from

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Creating_Android_Services

But in my case, my service just won't fire a notification after started (nor can I be sure that the service is running). Is there any way to make sure my service is running? Since when I tried to check on device's **System - Apps - Running** even my app is not listed. It's like my app just died (or sleep) after it lost focus/switch to other app

Below is my simple service & notification code

```
    function TAndroidServiceDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
      const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
    var TheNotif: TNotification;
    begin
      TheNotif := Notif.CreateNotification;
      try
        TheNotif.Title := 'Notif Title';
        TheNotif.Name := 'NotifServiceStart';
        TheNotif.AlertBody := 'I''m alive!!!!';
        TheNotif.FireDate := Now;
        Notif.PresentNotification(TheNotif);
      finally
        TheNotif.Free;
      end;
      Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY;
    end;
```

and this is my caller app code

```
    procedure TfmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    var FServiceConn: TLocalServiceConnection;
    begin
      FServiceConn := TLocalServiceConnection.Create;
      FServiceConn.StartService('unMainServiceLocation');
      FServiceConn.BindService('unMainServiceLocation');
    end;

    procedure TfmMain.NotifReceiveLocalNotification(Sender: TObject;
      ANotification: TNotification);
    begin
      Text1.Text :=
        'Title : ' + ANotification.Title + #13#10 +
        'Name : ' + ANotification.Name + #13#10 +
        'Alert : ' + ANotification.AlertBody ;
    end;
```

I tried to put a button on app and do the same thing (send notification from app) and when I pressed the button, my Text1 component shows the right thing, and the notification did appear, but not when starting my app (should've been started by the service). Service name *suppose to be* right since when I change the service name it got forced stopped (segmentation fault 11)

Please kindly give advice. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a service is running in Delphi 10 Seattle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262554/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-in-delphi-10-seattle)

Answer (score 0):

After having put this lines in other event (like a button click), it works fine:

```
FServiceConn.StartService('unMainServiceLocation');
FServiceConn.BindService('unMainServiceLocation');
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your variable `var FServiceConn: TLocalServiceConnection;` is limited to `FormCreate`, meaning it will not be available outside the `FormCreate` procedure. Place the variable up it in the `private` section of the form. Don't forget to clean up on closing / destroying the form.