# FMX - How to stop the service when swipe to close the app from recent list

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

The app is using `TJService.JavaClass._GetSTART_NOT_STICKY`.

The service will stop if the user exits the app.

However, if the user swipes to remove the app from the Recent list, the service is still running.

I need to stop the service when the user swipes away the app.

How can the app detect this and stop the service?

Comment: [What actually happens when you swipe an app out of the recent apps list?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19987/)

Comment: Could set the flag ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK or handle  onTaskRemoved in the service see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky)

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262554/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-in-delphi-10-seattle/34264464)